# I am not getting the posted input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a add task using jquery and javascript but when i type something and click on add task the value is not showing up I tried but it's not working for me though please let me know if it is possible or what I am doing wrong

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; 
var wrapper         = $(".task"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_task"); 
var a               = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById("set").innerHTML = a;
var x = 1; 
$(add_button).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ 
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append("<div id='set'><p>"+a+"</p><a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a></div>"); 
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
```

My html code

```
<div class="task">
<input type="text" value="" name='input' id="input" />
<button class="add_task">Add New Task</button>
<div id='set'><p></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your javascript is invalid. Check your developer tools console to pinpoint the problem line ... hint `e text`

Comment: What is that `e text` bdw in `remove`?

Comment: I see no event handler for button `add_task`. You are not doing anything on button click.

Comment: mistyping I coudn't find the way to remove it it was my typing mistake e text is nothing just typo error sorry for that

Comment: `e.text` it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the value of input inside the click event. Currently you are fetching it on dom ready, at that time it is empty. Then you are using that empty value to create the element.

```
 $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        a = $("#input").val();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append("<div id='set'><p>" + a + "</p><a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a></div>");
        }
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/170/)

Comment: @UsmanKhan atleast note the time of the answers. The answer you have accepted is the same answer as mine, but posted 10 minutes later then mine.

Comment: Sorry new here did not noticed about in hurry i accepted wrong one

Answer (score 0):

This maybe typing mistake

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove", function(e){ 
     e text //what is the use of this remove it then check it will work fine
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2te4Ly84/)

Answer (score 0):

Below fragment works fine.

```
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
        x++; //text box increment
        var a = document.getElementById('input').value;
        $(wrapper).append("<div id='set'><p>" + a + "</p><a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a></div>");
    }
});
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob37afb9/1/)

Comment: @UsmanKhan atleast note the time of the answers. The answer you have accepted is the same answer as mine, but posted 10 minutes later then mine